# Coordinate point not visible, label is visible

Tags: pgfplots

I'm expecting to see a solid black circular point at (2,2), but I'm not seeing anything.

Here's the code I'm using

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        restrict y to domain=-10:10,
        restrict x to domain=-5:5,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=4,
        xtick={-4,-2,...,4},
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=4,
        ytick={-4,-2,...,3},
        axis lines=center,
        axis equal,
        smooth,
        scale=0.8
    ]
    \addplot [] {(x-2)^3-3*x+6};
    \coordinate
    [
        label=above:{$(2,2)$},
        black,
        mark=*,
    ] (a) at (axis cs:2,2);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And what I'm getting out instead.
[image: The result of the code.]

So clearly the software can figure out that there is a coordinate at (2,2), but just isn't showing it. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: A \coordinate is not “visible”, nor does it support marks. You may be looking for \node.

Comment: You can use `\fill (a) circle[radius=1mm];` and adjust the radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coordinate does not have a (node) content. In order to keep your syntax almost completely, I added a style `cmark` that adds a plot mark at the center of the coordinate.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cmark/.style={label={[anchor=center]:\pgfuseplotmark{#1}}}]
    \begin{axis}
    [
        restrict y to domain=-10:10,
        restrict x to domain=-5:5,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=4,
        xtick={-4,-2,...,4},
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=4,
        ytick={-4,-2,...,3},
        axis lines=center,
        axis equal,
        smooth,
        scale=0.8
    ]
    \addplot [] {(x-2)^3-3*x+6};
    \coordinate
    [
        label=above:{$(2,2)$},
        black,
        cmark=*,
    ] (a) at (axis cs:2,2);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other options include the use of `node`s. Please note that if you use sufficiently recent version of pgfplots, e.g. `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`, you won't need the `axis cs:` prefix.

Comment: Thank you very much! Although this isn't strictly relevant, when I use a node instead, the point (circle) is way too big (probably because I'm using a tiny scale). Is there a way to get it smaller than I am currently making it using `\node[anchor=south, circle, fill, inner sep=0.5pt]
at (-2,2) {2,2};`?

Comment: @TheSheepGuy You can still scale it down, e.g. `\node[anchor=south, circle, fill, inner sep=0.5pt,scale=0.2] at (-2,2) {2,2};`, or, when you set the scale in the `tikzpicture` or `axis`, use `transform shape`, `\node[anchor=south, circle, fill, inner sep=0.5pt,transform shape] at (-2,2) {2,2};`.

Comment: Thank you very much!